# how to show bar-code scanning screen always?

Tags: android, barcode-scanner

How to show bar-code scanning screen always in android.

```
IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(activity);
```

Comment: can you add a little more of your code ?? which library are you using for barcode scanner ?

Comment: zxing library                                                                           IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(activity);
                integrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.QR_CODE_TYPES);
                integrator.setPrompt("Scan");
                integrator.setCameraId(0);
                integrator.setBeepEnabled(false);
                integrator.setBarcodeImageEnabled(false);
                integrator.initiateScan();

Comment: first things first : try adding these codes not in the comment and to your question , otherwise you will get more down votes ;) and second i write some sample codes below hope it solves your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you need to add a `FrameLayout` to your `layout.xml` as a container for barcodeScannet :

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/barcode_scanner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="350dp" />
```

after that you need to implement `ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler` in your activity or fragment

then you need to add scanner to this view

```
private ZXingScannerView mScannerView;

ViewGroup v = (ViewGroup) mainView.findViewById(R.id.barcode_scanner);
mScannerView = new ZXingScannerView(getActivity());
    v.addView(mScannerView);
```

also you need to override `onResume` and `onPause` to start stop the camera:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mScannerView.setResultHandler(this); // Register ourselves as a handler for scan results.
// aslso check for camera permission here too
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    mScannerView.stopCamera();           // Stop camera on pause
    super.onPause();
}
```

then :

```
@Override
public void handleResult(Result rawResult) {

    AppLog.logE("result content", rawResult.getText()); // Prints scan results
    AppLog.logE("result name", rawResult.getBarcodeFormat().toString()); // Prints the scan format (qrcode, pdf417 etc.)

   // the resault of barcode will be given as an string rawResult.getText()
   // and you can do whatEver you want with it
   // handleBarcodeResult(rawResult.getText());

    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mScannerView.resumeCameraPreview(BillPaymentFragment.this);
        }
    }, 2000);
}
```

and finally whenever you want to start the barcode scanner just call the following code :

```
mScannerView.startCamera();
```